How to start Memurai Redis cluster
I am trying to set up a simple Redis cluster on my local machine using Memurai. The documentation is a bit sparse on how to start a cluster. Right now I'm following this tutorial.
https://www.memurai.com/blog/understanding-sharding-enhancing-enterprise-performance-with-memurai
I have set cluster-enabled yes and cluster-config-file nodes.conf according to the tutorial.
Now the tutorial says the following:

Keep in mind that if you’re testing this setup on your local machine,
you’ll have to use a different value for each cluster-config-file
otherwise the next command will fail. Create the cluster Once you’ve
configured your instances in “cluster mode”, the next thing is to, in
fact, create the cluster. You can do that by running the following
command:
127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 --cluster-replicas 1

My question is: Where am I supposed to run this command? It doesn't look like a command to me, more like a sequence of arguments.

The command is actually missing in front of that IP:port list. This is the full line: "memurai-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 --cluster-replicas 1"
We'll edit the blog, thanks for noticing!
